# not getting all aws instances using python boto3 - problem with Reservation

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, instance, boto3

I have written a python-boto3 script to get all aws instances list from an account and region.

the script is running fine, but not giving all instances.

for example ,if  n instances are with same Reservation number then getting only one instance under Reservation.

please look at the below script , please help me how can I get all aws instances list irrespective of reservation number.

```
rg = 'us-west-2'
config = Config(
    retries = dict(
        max_attempts = 100
    )
)
ec = boto3.client('ec2', config=config, region_name=rg)

def get_tags():
    tag_list = []
    resp =  ec.describe_instances()['Reservations']
    #resp =  ec.describe_instances()
    #print(resp)
    tag_result = [['Name','InstanceId','State','t1:product','t1:environment-type','t1:environment-name']]
    for ec2 in resp:
    #for ec2 in resp["Reservation"]:
        #print(InstanceId)
        tag_list = []
```

Comment: thanks john , I am getting all instances list with running your script.

Answer (score 2):

In looking at your code, it's not obvious what you're trying to do, but here's some code that goes through all instances and shows their tags:

```py
import boto3

ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')

response = ec2_client.describe_instances()

for reservation in response['Reservations']:
    for instance in reservation['Instances']:
        print(instance['InstanceId'])
        for tag in instance['Tags']:
            print(tag['Key'], tag['Value'])
```

Here's the equivalent code using the boto3 resource method:

```py
import boto3

ec2_resource = boto3.resource('ec2')

for instance in ec2_resource.instances.all():
    print(instance.id)
    for tag in instance.tags:
        print(tag['Key'], tag['Value'])
```

Please note that `InstanceId` and `State` are available directory on the instances object. They are not Tags.

Comment: Hi John, Thank you ,  I have ran your script , it is working fine and getting all instances correctly . I want to export the output  to excel file. ,

Comment: There should be some Python libraries that understand Excel file formats, or you could simply save as CSV for loading into Excel. If you run into a problem, feel free to create another Question with details of the problems you're facing.