# not getting complete aws ec2 list

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-ec2, boto3

I have written a python-boto3 script to get all aws instances list from an account and region.
the script is running fine and getting output in csv format as expected(getting only one instance under one reservation number , so remaining instances are missing )
 problem is not getting all aws instances list correctly.
for example ,
 I have total 5 instances in aws account
             Instance-1 and Instance-2 are with  Reservation1 number 
             Instance-3 and Instance-4 are with  Reservation2 number
             Instance-5 is with Reservation3 number
 I am getting only 3 instances list in csv format instead of 5 instances.
please look at the below script , please help me how can I get all aws instances list irrespective of reservation number.

```
output = "Prod.csv"    
     ec = boto3.client('ec2', config=config, region_name=rg)

        def get_tags():
            tag_list = []
            resp =  ec.describe_instances()
            tag_result = [['Name','InstanceId','State','bt:product','bt:environment-type','bt:environment-name']]
            for ec2 in resp['Reservations']:
                tag_list = []
                try:
                    ecName = next(item for item in ec2['Instances'][0]['Tags'] if item['Key'] == 'Name')['Value']
                    tag_list.append(ecName)
                except:
                    ecName = 'Null'
                    tag_list.append(ecName)
                insId = ec2['Instances'][0]['InstanceId']
                instanceID = str(insId)
                tag_list.append(instanceID)
                state = ec2['Instances'][0]['State']['Name']
                tag_list.append(state)
                try:
                    btprod = next(item for item in ec2['Instances'][0]['Tags'] if item['Key'] == 'bt:product')['Value']
                    tag_list.append(btprod)
                except:
                    btprod = 'Null'
                    tag_list.append(btprod)
                try:
                    btenvtype = next(item for item in ec2['Instances'][0]['Tags'] if item['Key'] == 'b1:environment-type')['Value']
                    tag_list.append(btenvtype)
                except:
                    btenvtype = 'Null'
                    tag_list.append(btenvtype)
                try:
                    btenvname = next(item for item in ec2['Instances'][0]['Tags'] if item['Key'] == 'b1:environment-name')['Value']
                    tag_list.append(btenvname)
                except:
                    btenvname = 'Null'
                    tag_list.append(btenvname)
                tag_result.append(tag_list)
            return tag_result
        def main():

            tag = get_tags()
            with open(output,'w') as resultFile:
                wr = csv.writer(resultFile, dialect='excel')
                wr.writerows(tag)
                log = open(output, 'r').read()
```

Comment: What debug have you done? Have you been able to identify if they're being retrieved in resp? Are you getting a "NextToken" back. If you are you will need to pass this back in and run the request again with an "NextToken" argument.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated version of the program based upon the answer I provided in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62060100/174777):

```py
import boto3
import csv

output = "Prod.csv"    
ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')

def get_tag(instance, tag_name):

    # Find tag on instance
    if 'Tags' in instance:
        for tag in instance['Tags']:
            if tag['Key'] == tag_name:
                return tag['Value']

    # Not found
    return 'Null'

def get_all_tags():

    # Add header row
    tag_result = [['Name','InstanceId','State','bt:product','bt:environment-type','bt:environment-name']]

    response = ec2_client.describe_instances()

    for reservation in response['Reservations']:
        for instance in reservation['Instances']:

            tag_list = []
            tag_list.append(get_tag(instance, 'Name'))
            tag_list.append(instance['InstanceId'])
            tag_list.append(instance['State']['Name'])

            for tag in ['bt:product','bt:environment-type','bt:environment-name']:
                tag_list.append(get_tag(instance, tag))

            tag_result.append(tag_list)

    return tag_result

def main():

    all_tags = get_all_tags()
    with open('output.csv','w') as resultFile:
        wr = csv.writer(resultFile, dialect='excel')
        wr.writerows(all_tags)

main()
```